# Downgrading boost from on FreeBSD

Tags: boost, version, freebsd, downgrade

For some old project that I'm using, I need to have FreeBSD and the project requires boost library. However, it was using boost-1_52_0 whereas ports have boost-1_55_0.

According to [this](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~reinholz/freebsd/portdowngrade.html), it should be really easy and straight forward, BUT `portdowngrade` is not even under `sysutils` anymore. It is quite outdated and not quite straight forward anymore. There is no prompt in `portdowngrade` anymore. Also when I try `man portdowngrade`, it say `no manual for portdowngrade` and no `help` either.

I continued to search and find [this](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/install-older-versions-of-a-port-or-package.49934/), in which old versions should be under `/var/cache/pkg`, but no luck again.

I found the `boost-lib-1_52_0`(not source, just pkg distribution etc. which is like in the ports, downloading source and installing) and it does sanity check and says the port is outdated.

Finally, I couldn't find a way to install different versions with `pkg install`.

I have to use FreeBSD and I want to use boost-lib-1_52_0 because I have to solve a lot of other problems with 1_55_0.

Any help is appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this repo branch](http://pkg.freebsd.org/freebsd:10:x86:64/) (adjust it accordingly to your FreeBSD version and arch) to install boost 1.52 with `pkg`. To point `pkg` to this repo create `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/old.conf` file with following content:

```
old: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:10:x86:64/release_0",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  signature_type: "fingerprints",
  fingerprints: "/usr/share/keys/pkg",
  enabled: yes
}
```

Now run `pkg search boost` to make sure `boost-libs-1.52` is available.

Another way would be checking out ports tree with `svn` on some older revision that have boost-libs port at version 1.52 and then building it.

Comment: I've done all and now I can see `boost-libs-1.52.0_2` is available. But I wonder how am I going to fetch and install it. `pkg install boost` seems to install `boost-libs-1.55` and old version doesn't seem to be under ports. I'm not sure how am I going to make it default.

Comment: Set version explicitly: `pkg install boost-libs-1.52.0_2`.

Comment: I did as you said, but it tries to download `boost-libs-1.55.0_8` and bunch of more programs. I accepted even thought the old boost is not in the download list and I see that 1_55 is installed (from `/usr/local/include/boost/version.hpp`)

Comment: By the way, when I search for boost, it says `pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:10:x86:32/release_0/meta.txz` not found. But it  finds the old boost.

Comment: Hum, well, you can `fetch http://pkg.freebsd.org/freebsd:10:x86:32/release_0/All/boost-libs-1.52.0_2.txz` manually, and then do `pkg add fetched_file.txz`

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of this.